# Drawing a crossbow with or without drawing apparatus

Tags: archery

A crossbow I purchased (a Stryker 380) came with a drawing apparatus made of cord and a couple plastic parts. I haven't been using it since drawing with fingers works just fine. But now I'm wondering if the apparatus is not just for ease of drawing, but is also for safety. Are there safety considerations, or is it just for convenience?

Comment: just a 50% less resistance because of the pulley system, it doesnt even have a centering reason in this crossbow as it should center the string by design even pulling with your fingers

Comment: Yeah, it centers just fine.

Answer (score 2):

If I had done a little more homework, I would have found a manual online for this closely related bow. It describes drawing the bow either way.

http://www.strykerxbow.com/downloads/OMDesertStryker07.pdf

It says:

```
MANUAL DRAW
Place the arch of foot in bow stirrup. Using both hands firmly grasp
close to the center of the string and draw the string back until you
hear it click firmly in place.

OPTIONAL EZ2DRAW COCKING AID
(Description of how to use that.)
```

Comment: the thing is seriously named `EZ2DRAW`?